# Eventbus in Vue.js isn't updating my component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two components and I want to display what the user enters in one on the other component. I don't really want to use a state manager like vuex because it's probably a bit overkill as it's a small application

this is my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { routes }from './routes';

export const EventBus = new Vue();

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Component that emits the event called addHtml.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Add HTML</h1>
        <hr>
        <button @click="navigateToHome" class="btn btn-primary">Go to Library</button>
        <hr>
        Title <input type="text" v-model="title">
        <button @click="emitGlobalClickEvent()">Press me</button>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
  import { EventBus } from '../../main.js'

  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        title: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      navigateToHome() {
        this.$router.push('/');
      },
      emitGlobalClickEvent() {
        console.log(this.title);
        EventBus.$emit('titleChanged', this.title);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

the file that listens for the event thats emitted and to display what was entered on the other component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Existing Items</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>{{ test }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { EventBus } from '../main.js';

    export default {
      data: function () {
        return {
          test: ''
        }
      },
      created() {
        EventBus.$on('titleChanged', (data) => {
          console.log('in here!',data);
          this.test = data;
        });
      }
    }

</script>
```

the `console.log('in here!',data);` inside the listener gets printed out to the console so I know it's picking it up however `{{ test }}` doesn't get updated to what the user enters when I click back onto the component to view if it was updated, it just remains blank? Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe it is like Reiner said, because the component gets destroyed if you switch pages. Try wrapping your `router-view` inside a `keep-alive`: `<keep-alive><router-view></router-view></keep-alive>. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#keep-alive

Comment: Fantastic did this and it worked, it was getting destroyed each time and being reset! Thanks, if you post it as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like Reiner said, because the component gets destroyed once you switch pages. Try wrapping your router-view inside a keep-alive:

```
<keep-alive>
  <router-view><router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

Also. If you want to keep the state of just one specific component / page you can use the `include` tag:

```
<keep-alive include='name of component'>
  <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vue-router to display the secound component. The reason might be that you just see a new instance of that component everytime and the value of `test` will be reseted when the component is destroyed. You can bind it to a (global) variable to persist  `test: window.yourApp.test`. Maybe webpack will mourn but it is possible. Even eslint has an ignore comment for such cases.

Comment: you were right it was getting reset each time, thank you! just wrapped the <keep-alive> around the <router-view> and it worked

Comment: ;) your " when I click back onto the component to view if it was updated" was a hint